# Is it possible to find the distance between two networked devices?

Tags: networking

Is it possible to find out how far away another device, within the same network, is from my computer? Are there any programs that can do this?

I decided to use the formula `distance = speed * time`, where time would be the minimum rtt of the `ping` command and speed was `346m/s`

The `ping` command doesn't seem to always be accurate and sometimes gives varying results. Sometimes the ping time is `30ms`, then `1ms` and then `50ms`. Using `ping` on my computer, I get more accurate results that using my phone, which often gives a few 100 milliseconds.

`346m/s` comes from the speed of sound in air at a temperature of 25°C. I'm not sure if that is the correct speed that I should be using. The speed also doesn't account for all the obstacles, like walls, that the information/packets have to travel through.

After doing a few calculations using the above formula, speed and ping time, I figured out that this method of calculating distance to another device on the same network doesn't work.

Does anybody have any ideas on how this could be done?

Comment: Using the speed of sound is complete nonsense. Both radio waves like Wifi and ethernet signals in a cable travel at lightspeed (~300000 km/s).

Comment: And more apropos to the question, ask your favorite search engine about the 500-mile email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variability of the results is due to switch congestion, processor load, emf interference, etc. etc.

I don't think you could ever get reliable results using that method. However, you use a lower level technique to achieve something similar:

For cabled networks have a look into CAT5/6 cable testers which can provide a usually good estimate of the cable length. Fluke Networks products would be a good starting point to investigate what is possible, although you'll probably want something cheaper!

For WiFi investigate Free Space Path Loss.

Comment: Is it possible to do this with Wi-Fi?

Comment: @user2556381: No.  These devices work by measuring signal attenuation, which is a good indicator of ethernet cable length. This is not possible at all with Wifi, as you can't tell if a device is behind a wall in 1m or 300m away on an open field based on the signal strength. Variations on processing time make measuring bases on time (like with GPS) impossible as these variations are likely several magnitudes higher then the time intervals you need to measure.

Comment: although you didn't specifically mention wifi, from what you said it is fairly obvious that's what you meant, so sorry! investigate free space path loss. I have updated my answer accordingly